# How to detect polynomials in Java

Tags: java, string, character

Suppose I have a polynomial -x^2 + 2x - 1 = 0. It is read from a file.

I have the code that analyzes each character of the polynomial.

I want to create an extra step that compacts the polynomial(so the white spaces gets eliminated) so I can check if the string is in fact a polynomial which I can easily do by just checking the last 2 index of the polynomial which is the equal sign and the zero like this: (=0)

Problem is some polynomial length have different lengths which gave me the thought to use an ArrayList. Problem is I cannot declare my ArrayList to be of type Character to store each character in the sequential index of an ArrayList.

```
public void createEquationNoWhiteSpaces(){
    // it cannot be done because there is no ArrayList of characters
    textArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
        // Store the characters of the polynomial in an ArrayList
        // because each polynomial has different length
        if(text.charAt(i) != ' ')
            textArrayList = text.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, you can't just check for "the equal sign and the zero like this: (=0)" to check whether a string is a polynomial.  What if your program were given the string "e^x = 0"?  If your problem domain  includes nothing but root-finding for polynomials, then you don't have to worry about that, but the question doesn't make this clear.

Comment: whats wrong with strings? or you could go for the traditional representation - a vector of coefficients

Comment: @AdamMihalcin this is why I wanted to create this extra step which is to do the charAt method on the string and store each character that is not a white-space in an ArrayList of type Character. So even if the polynomial was spaced out, the program can adjust to this. But I can't make an ArrayList of type Character for some reason.

Comment: @radai The idea was to detect each character of the polynomial in the file. I forgot to mention there are some that are not polynomials in the file instead are just bad inputs for example: pig, grass etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an array, you can certainly declare an `ArrayList<Character>`. However, you might want to use a `StringBuilder` instead of a list for this purpose anyway.

Comment: I will try using StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

```
st.replaceAll("\\s","")
```

removes all whitespace in string st

Comment: I do not understand how this method work. The first argument has a black-slash and no whitespaces.

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum \s is a pattern for all whitespaces